# Quotes prevent auto-linking Stack Exchange question URLs, but the preview doesn't reflect this?

Tags: bug, edits, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

Compare this preview of editing a post (the same is true when writing):

[image: preview of a question being written showing quotes around a raw url producing quotes around the auto-titled link]

With the results:

[image: posted question with the raw url surrounded by quotes]

Can this get fixed at some point?